# Django Delete and Move Uploaded Files when Model Deleted

Tags: python, django

I have this code for when my model is deleted so that the files are deleted too.  I also want it to move the files to a folder only the admin can see right before they are deleted.

Here is my code:

```
@receiver(post_delete, sender=ClientUpload)
def clientupload_postdelete(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.file:
        #with f as open(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/uploads/Recycle/' + instance.file.name, 'w+'):
        #   f.write(instance.file)
        #   f.close()
        #   logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        #   logger.info("File %s moved to %s" % (instance.file.name, settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/uploads/Recycle'))
        # Pass false so FileField doesn't save the model.
        instance.file.delete(False)
    else:
        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        logger.warning("Failed to find file %s for deletion." % instance.file.name)
```

The commented out parts are commented out because they were raising this error:
SyntaxError: Can't assign to function call. On the line `with f as open(...)`.  I'm not sure why, but that is supposed to be the part where it saves the file into another directory before deleting it.  What am I doing wrong here?  How can I write the file to another directory before I delete it?

Also is postdelete correct here or should I use predelete?

Finally, is instance.file.name the correct way to get the file's name in this situation?  Or will just instance.file do the job?  This is the first signal I've done so I am unsure and even with the documentation I'm having trouble getting it to work.

A small example would work wonders, thanks in advance

Comment: What error was it raising?

Comment: SyntaxError: Can't assign to function call. On the line `with f as open(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What error were you getting exactly? "SyntaxError: can't assign to function call"? Because the with syntax is wrong. You're trying to assign `f` to `open()`, when it's the other way around:

```
with open(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/uploads/Recycle/' + instance.file.name, 'w+') as f:
# ...rest of the code
```

Try that change, and next time please post the Traceback to make debugging easier for us.

As for the signal type: post_delete is fine. The instance you're getting is no longer on the DB but contains the info you need (the file).

As for the question regarding `instance.file.name`, today I expected `.name` to return only the filename but it didn't. The way I got the filename was using `os.path.basename`. But in your case it's unnecessary

```
import os

filename = os.path.basename(instance.file.path)
```

Comment: Awesome exactly what I needed, as for the instance.metadata_file part, what exactly is this?  Nevermind you seem to have removed in your edit

Comment: My son was (is) hilariously distracting me and I accidentally posted reference code from work :P

Comment: Haha :)  So rather than instance.file.name I basically just use filename instead which I get via the os.path.basename method you described

Comment: Seems to be working now.  Unless you see anything else wrong, I think I am good.  There are no other steps I need to take to have this signal fire correct?

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be the case. I was lazy and didn't check the documentation, but now I did and it states that [`File.name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/files/file/#django.core.files.File.name) returns the path from MEDIA_ROOT, not just the filename.

Comment: Yes I see that now, I supposed I could just trim it from the last / onward, but your method seems better :)

Comment: I imagine that's what basename does :P That should be enough. In fact, if you got the exception in the first case it means the signal triggered. Good luck!

Comment: Great :) Thanks for the follow up. Was a silly mistake I made, had been  using C# for too long Python was neglected.  But ended up answering a bunch more questions for me so thanks a ton!